# skip frames and seek to end of rtsp stream in opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, stream, frame, rtsp

I am trying to use RTSP stream, but I just want the last frame every certain execution time:

```
while True
    image.get()
    #EXECUTE STUFF AROUND 0.1seconds
```

I am using the following code on a RTSP stream of a 25fps camera. The problem is that after around 5 minutes of working perfectly fine, the cv2.VideoCapture stream stops to return an image (returns False flag). Why is that?

```
import threading 
from threading import Lock
import cv2


rtsp_link = "rtsp://url"
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture(rtsp_link)

latest_frame = None
last_ret = None
lo = Lock()

def rtsp_cam_buffer(vcap):
    global latest_frame, lo, last_ret
    while True:
        with lo:
            last_ret, latest_frame = vcap.read()


t1 = threading.Thread(target=rtsp_cam_buffer,args=(vcap,),name="rtsp_read_thread")
t1.daemon=True
t1.start()


while True :
    if (last_ret is not None) and (latest_frame is not None):
        img = latest_frame.copy()
    else:
        print("unable to read the frame")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        continue
```

The time until the cv2.videocapture stream stops receiving frames it's irregular, sometimes it's seconds, and now it has been working 15 minutes. How?!

No error is shown on the screen when RTSP stream stops receiving images.

Comment: Are you getting any error after the python code finishes abruptly?

Comment: you're gonna have to run the stream reception in a thread, and keep the latest frame around (in a variable) for when you need it. -- you can't throttle the stream. if you don't read in a timely manner, frames WILL QUEUE UP. eventually, the whole thing will give up. it will not drop frames.

Comment: @PrashantMaurya No :(

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Isn't it what I am actually doing in the code?

Comment: oh right, yeah, that's what you do in the thread... ok so either the lock is in the way, but I don't think so, or the network stream is simply bad, or your network connection is bad -- you should debug this by running the stream in VLC of ffplay

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz The issue was indeed the network connection. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some people in the comments have said, the issue was not the code. Doing it with threading works perfectly fine.

The issue was that the connection to the camera was very bad. I lost 50% of the packets when I did PING cameraIP.

Nonetheless, I change the code, and added a condition, that if none image is received during more than 30 seconds, reconnect the camera, executing cv2.VideoCapture again.

Comment: did you update the original code? thanks